# Entity framework code first

Tags: ef-code-first

I'm using EntityFramework.Patterns in my application and I need to implement soft deletion.  Is it possible to implement it using ArchivableRepository ?

If yes can you describe how ?

Comment: I've done a soft delete with repository pattern, but I'm not sure what you mean by ArchivableRepository?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a soft delete by adding an interface to the entity's that support soft deletion.

```
public interface ISoftDelete
{
    DateTime? DeletedDate {get;set;}
}

public class Foo : ISoftDelete
{
   public int Id { get;set; }
   public DateTime? DeletedDate { get;set; }
}
```

Then in your Repository, add something like this

```
public void SoftDelete<T>(T entity) where T : class, IEntity
{
    entity.DeletedDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
}
```

Usage is like this

```
var entity = repo.GetOne();
repo.SoftDelete(entity);
repo.SaveChanges();
```